# Use React to parse a file (serverless)

Tags: design, web-development, web-applications, aws, react

I have a design question and am hoping for some validation.  I want to create a 'serverless' web app which will parse a csv file and return an XML file.

I will have a single page react app hosted in AWS S3, where a user can drag and drop a file, and it will be parsed and the contents of the csv file will be sent to a lambda, which will then convert it to an XML file and return this to the user.

I am hoping not to have to use S3 to store the csv and resulting xml file but I can if that is needed.

Is this possible without a server or am I way off?

Comment: If this is posted in the wrong place let me know

Comment: What does the Lambda do (besides change the data format)?

Comment: Do you have file read write permissions on the users computer in your setup?

Comment: The lambda would convert the file to XML but I'm guessing I could do all this client side with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work. I've done a SPA out of file storage with API services on Azure recently.

You will need to configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on the client and the lambda. The browser will consider the API request cross-origin because it's not going to the site where it got the HTML from.

You likely will need a form of external authentication like OAuth/OpenID Connect

A code sample can be found [here](https://codeburst.io/asynchronous-file-upload-with-node-and-react-ea2ed47306dd)